# I can not create PHP array from JSON

Tags: php, arrays

I have a complicated JSON and I need create array from this JSON.
I already parsed JSON and create a variablies like this:

```
  $name = $json[response][docs][$i][name][0];
  $osm_id = $json[response][docs][$i][osm_id][0];
  $place = $json[response][docs][$i][place][0];
  $population= $json[response][docs][$i][population][0];
```

now I need a array, with this variablies, where the `$i` is changing, like this:

```
$array = [array_1(name,osm_id,place,population),array_2(name_2,osm_id_2)]
```

Can you help me with the cycle to fill this array?

Comment: you need to quote each array element first of all `$json[response]...` needs to be `$json['response']...`

Comment: Please provide us a [mcve]. I have no idea what the problem is.

Answer (score 1):

If my understanding is correct,

```
$expected_arr = array();
foreach($json[response][docs] as $inc => $values){
   $data = array();
   foreach($values as $key => $val){
      $data[$key] = $val[0];
   }
   $expected_arr[$inc] = $data;
}
```

So you would get something like

```
array(0 => array( 'name'=>'xxx', 'osm_id'=>'yy',..), 1=> array('name'=>'',.. ,),...)
```

Comment: yes, you understood it, but i dont know how to use it...

Comment: Just give a try by paste this code where you want to have this array. If i am wrong, could you explain, what exactly you want to do?

Comment: I used that code, then I print_r( $expected_arr); and it show me this: Array ( [name] => Array ( [0] => B ) [osm_id] => Array ( [0.... In name is just the letter B, not whole name, and osm_id is empty

Comment: I have updated the code. Try it now. Obviously i had a mistake there. But that was just an idea. You could just walk around the code and could have find the answer by yourself. Let know if you got that ;) :)

Comment: yes, that is OK, thank you. when i want to show echo $expected_arr[0];
it will write "Array" can I show all value of $expected_arr[0] ? if i want $expected_arr[0][name], that is going OK.

Comment: `$expected_arr[0]` is also an array. So you need to use `print_r($expected_arr[0])`. If everything works for you, am i worth make this answer as correct answer? ;) :)

Comment: thank you, you helped me :)